# When writing a new blog post error message ' sorry, you are not allowed to edit this page '

Tags: errors

We haven't accessed our website for a couple of months, but while I am logged in today, I cannot write a new blog post. I write it and press 'submit for review' or save as draft and I get a white screen with 'sorry you are not allowed to edit this page.

I cannot code, so in need of a simple solution! I tried to download the newest version and was sent to another screen that said 'wordpress is already downloading'

I don't know if this is part of the issue.

others have mentioned this happening after renaming plug ins, I haven't done this and don't know how if this is part of the solution.

Comment: It sounds like you may have been hacked, as the "submit for review" button only appears for certain roles - in Core, only appears for Contributors. You may need to go into your database and update your user to have admin rights. You can contact your host for support with that part. In the meantime, it would also be very wise to contact a security company - popular security plugins also offer paid audits - and have them check your site to see if it's been hacked, and fix it if so.

Comment: You can also try disabling all plugins by going into either FTP or a host-provided File Manager and renaming your /wp-content/plugins/ folder, and try switching themes by deleting the folder containing the current theme so WP is forced to go to a default theme. That way you can check if it is just a plugin or a theme causing issues.